# Cannot update Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, update-manager

I cannot get updates to work.

Here is message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installed
              Depends: libwayland-cursor0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installed
```

When I run `apt get -f` it says I do not have permission.

Please help.

Comment: you should be able to solve the permitions issue by running `sudo apt get -f`

Comment: you need to run `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 1):

The package you are installing has its dependencies. To install it, install the dependencies first.

Issue this command on the terminal.

`sudo apt-get install -f`

This command will attempt to correct the broken dependencies of the package.